# Using XSLT to transform XML to C++ initializer list

Tags: c++, xslt, functional-programming

I've been trying to use XSLT to transform an XML into C++ code. I have fields that represent class member variables, with information like their type. For example:

```
<members> 
    <member name="Attribute1" type="int" length="32" />
    <member name="Attribute2" type="string" length="64" />
    <member name="Attribute3" type="char array" length="10" />
    <member name="Attribute4" type="unsigned int" length="32" />
</members>
```

However, I really can't seem to come up with any way to write a proper initialisation list for constructors. My main problem comes from the C++ syntax:

```
ClassName:ClassName()
: Attribute1(value),
  Attribute2(value),
  Attribute4(value)
{
    memset(Attribute3, 0, typeof(Attribute));
}
```

The part that is giving me trouble is the fact that the last member initialized is not followed by a comma. This is should be an easy problem, but XSLT's functional + declarative nature is giving me hell. Here is what I have considered so far:

1) Create a printInitialisationList template which has a "firstMemberPrinted" param. If this param is false, we print a comma and a newline first. If it is true (meaning this is the first member being printed), we don't print the comma. The problem with this, however, is that since variables are immutable in XSLT, I can't actually create a variable to pass in and change the value once the I have printed a member.

2) I thought about solving #1 by simply checking if a "printed" variable had already been created, and if not, to pass True into firstMemberPrinted and then create the variable. However, since XSLT is a declarative language, the idea of checking for an undeclared variable doesn't actually make sense.

3) Checking if "position() = last" doesn't help, since the last member could very well just be an array, which needs to be initialized inside the braces.

Note that I can't change the format of the XML file :(

I would appreciate all and any help! Thanks!

Comment: Is XSLT a must? If not, you can parse the XML file and write the generation code in c++.

Comment: Is the C++ sample you posted the result you want to generate from the XML sample you posted too? I don't see any use of the `name`, `type` and `length` attribute values at all.

Comment: I am working on this at my job and this system has been in place for awhile, so unfortunately XSLT is a must =(

Comment: @MartinHonnen ah, sorry for the confusion. The type and length would be used in the member declaration in the .h file; the constructor initializer however would be in the .cpp file. I will update the sample to use the name.